# Add param with html in angular translator

Tags: angular, angular-translate

I have a translation like this one:

```
{
    layout_with_variable: 'Blabla blabla {{VARIABLE}}'
}
```

And I would like to use Angular translate to do something like this :

```
<p>{{'layout_with_variable'|translate:{VARIABLE: '<a href="tel:' + variable2 + '">' + variable2 + '</a>'}}}</p>
```

But I get the error `Unclosed string literal` and the string is not interpreted and just displayed like that in the webpage.

How can I add a variable with html tag inside a translation with Angular 4 ?

Could you help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Why pipe content into an html tag? Couldn't you use the pipe in "{{ }}" and leave the html static in the template?

Comment: @rjustin I don't understand the part "leave the html static in the template?", the thing is we have existing translations already and we cannot really modifies them.

Comment: You are dynamically adding html here: {VARIABLE: '<a href="tel:' + variable2 + '">' + variable2 + '</a>'}. Why not leave this in then ngIf it if necessary

Comment: @rjustin The thing is that in english it would be ok, but in other langage, chinese by exemple some number are in the beginning or something like that so we can't move it out of the translator.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use the attribute [innerHTML] in your p:

```
<p [innerHTML]="'layout_with_variable'|translate:{VARIABLE:'<a href=tel:' + variable2 + '>' + variable2 + '</a>'}"></p>
```

With `variable2` initiated in your component.